# Implement LZMA compress/decompress

Tags: c++, windows, lzma

#### Background

I have a `VS2015` C++ solution containing many projects. My output run under Windows environment only.

I need to add a Utility functions to my project that will handle LZMA data.

Naturally, I went and got me the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).

#### Preparations

I've extracted all `.c` & `.h` files from `LZMA SDK` and added them into my project.

Then, I consulted this post, [LZMA SDK - How to Use](http://www.asawicki.info/news_1368_lzma_sdk_-_how_to_use.html)
, and implement 2 utility functions:

```
bool DecompressLZMA(_In_ const ByteVector& vecIn, _Out_ ByteVector& vecOut)
bool CompressLZMA(_In_ const ByteVector& vecIn, _Out_ ByteVector& vecOut)
```

I tested the code by calling `CompressLZMA` and then `DecompressLZMA` to verify a full cycle.

#### Problem

`CompressLZMA` call passed successfully, however `DecompressLZMA` call generated result `SZ_ERROR_INPUT_EOF`

#### Question

What am I doing wrong?

#### Code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "LZMA/LzmaLib.h"

using ByteVector = vector < byte >;

bool Cast(const ByteVector& vecByte, string& res)
{
    string strTmp(&vecByte[0], &vecByte[0] + vecByte.size());
    res = strTmp;
    return true;
}

bool Cast(const string& strVal, ByteVector& vecByte)
{
    vecByte = vector<BYTE>(&strVal[0], &strVal[0] + strVal.length());
    return true;
}

bool DecompressLZMA(_In_ const ByteVector& vecIn, _Out_ ByteVector& vecOut)
{
    try
    {
        int iLZMA_PROPS_SIZE = LZMA_PROPS_SIZE;
        vecOut.resize(vecIn.size() * 10);
        unsigned dstLen = vecOut.size();
        unsigned srcLen = vecIn.size() - iLZMA_PROPS_SIZE;
        SRes res = LzmaUncompress(
            &vecOut[0], &dstLen,
            &vecIn[iLZMA_PROPS_SIZE], &srcLen,
            &vecIn[0], iLZMA_PROPS_SIZE);
        assert(res == SZ_OK);
        if (res == SZ_OK) {
            vecOut.resize(dstLen);
            return true;
        }

    }

    // nothing to do. just return false
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    return false;
}

bool CompressLZMA(_In_ const ByteVector& vecIn, _Out_ ByteVector& vecOut)
{
    try
    {
        unsigned propsSize = LZMA_PROPS_SIZE;
        unsigned destLen = vecIn.size() + vecIn.size() / 3 + 128;
        vecOut.resize(propsSize + destLen);

        int res = LzmaCompress(
            &vecOut[LZMA_PROPS_SIZE], &destLen,
            &vecIn[0], vecIn.size(),
            &vecOut[0], &propsSize,
            -1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1);

        assert(propsSize == LZMA_PROPS_SIZE);
        assert(res == SZ_OK);

        vecOut.resize(propsSize + destLen);
        return true;
    }

    // nothing to do. just return false
    catch (...)
    {
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string strTest = "a test string";
    ByteVector vec1, vec2, vec3;
    Cast(strTest, vec1);

    CompressLZMA(vec1, vec2);
    DecompressLZMA(vec2, vec3);

    string strTestCycle;
    Cast(vec3, strTestCycle);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have a VS2015 C++ solution containing many projects.* I don't know if this helps you, but `vcpkg` has a port of `liblzma`. https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/liblzma

Comment: `LZMA SDK` is a mess. I suggest you to try `XZ Utils` (http://tukaani.org/xz/), which implements `LZMA2` and is easier to use.

Comment: @akappa, does `LZMA2` help me compress `LZMA` format?

Comment: @idanshmu: it also supports `LZMA` if you specifically need that.

Comment: XZ Utils should be a lest just as messy! See this very critical report about the [XZ](https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/xz_inadequate.html) format. I would bet the best solution would be [zlip](https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip.html) (single-thread) or [pzlip](https://www.nongnu.org/lzip/plzip.html) (multi-thread).